# Rearranging logarithmic equation

Tags: statistics, logarithms

I've tried hard to rearrange the following equation to calculate the (AGE)

$$\mu=18.8144+(-1.8443\log(\text{age}))+(-1.4032\log(\text{SBP}))+(-0.3899\cdot\text{Smoke})+(-0.5390\log(\text{TC}/\text{HDL})).$$

For example if someone with 
$\mu=3.13422$,
$\text{SBP}= 140$,
$\text{smoke}= 1$, and
$\text{TC}/\text{HDL}= 5$

The age will be 55 years, But I could not arrange it in an appropriate way to get the right results.

Could you please help?

Comment: What *have* you tried?

Comment: I've tried this http://alturl.com/6dtg6

Comment: That link is dead.

Comment: Sorry, \[Log Age= (Mu - 18.8144 - (-1.4032log(SBP)) - (-0.5390log(TC/HDL)))/ -1.8443\]

Comment: Are you aware that the natural logarithm $\log\colon\Bbb R_+\to \Bbb R$ is the inverse of the exponential function $\exp\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R_+$?

Comment: Iam weak at this, I never worked with log for more than 10 years, I use this equation to calculate health risk, and trying to use it to get the age if the risk is known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully the process will become clear if we generalize the expression with some arbitrary constants:

$\mu=18.8144+(-1.8443\log(\text{age}))+(-1.4032\log(\text{SBP}))+(-0.3899\cdot\text{Smoke})+(-0.5390\log(\text{TC}/\text{HDL}))$

is isomorphically converted to:

$$a = b-c\log d + E \log f + gh + i\log j$$ and we want to solve for $d$ = age. Note how the mathematical constant $e$ is NOT used as the coefficients/arguments in the above expression; we will need $e \approx 2.71828...$ later to solve for $d$.

Solving for ("isolating") $d$: $$a = b-c\log d + E \log f + gh + i\log j \\ 
a - b - E\log f - gh -i \log j = - c \log d \\ - c \log d = a - b - E \log f - gh -i \log j \\ c\log d = -a+b+E\log  f + gh + i\log j \\ \log d = \frac{-a+b+E\log  f + gh + i\log j}{c} \\ d = e^{\bigg(\dfrac{-a+b+E\log  f + gh + i\log j}{c}\bigg)}$$

I suggest labeling each constant ($a=\mu, b=18.8144, c=-1.8443, etc.)$ and then plugging in the values when you have $d$ = age on side of the equation.

Comment: Thank you This is helpful Based on your comment the Age then can be calculated: \[Age=e^((-3.2 + 18.8144 + (-1.4032log(140)) + (-0.5390log(5)) + (-0.3899)) / -1.8443)\]
  However, I still can't get the 55

Comment: @Hages You're welcome for the answer! I gather from your comment that you set $\mu = 3.2$. However, your original problem statement says $\mu = 3.13422$. Check your work again to make sure your variables are correct.

Comment: Yah Sorry i also tried it this way but still not luck, will keep trying. \[e^((-3.13422 + 18.8144 + (-1.4032log(140)) + (-0.5390log(5)) + (-0.3899)) / -1.8443)\]

Comment: I answered using the $\log$ notation because you included it in the problem. Are you sure it is not defined to be a base-10 logarithm ($\log_{10}$) or is the problem really asking for a natural logarithm ($\log_{e} = \ln) ?

Comment: the coefficients are from logistic regression so I assume it Natural log

Comment: I think I messed up in setting $c$ equal to a negative constant in the last line of my answer...dividing by a positive 1.8443 in the exponent is probably more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

The natural logarithm $\log\colon\Bbb R_+\to \Bbb R$ is the inverse of the exponential function $\exp\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R_+$. This means that for any positive $x$, $\exp(\log x)(=e^{\log x})=x$.